# pytest allure. Генерация html отчета

Tags: python, allure, pytest

Подскажите пожалуйста, как работает pytest allure.
В данной инструкции вообще все просто - `https://pypi.org/project/allure-pytest/`.
Скачал, но:

1. При команде
   `py -m pytest --alluredir=%allure_result_folder% ./tests` генерирует тесты.
2. А вот при `py -m allure serve %allure_result_folder%`
   ничего не происходит.

Дальше с помощью видео узнал https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6qASwPL86MM,
что можно сделать таким образом. И да все заработало.

Поэтому есть вопросы:

1. Для allure обязательна Java(не хочется загружать Java только из-за этого)?
2. Работает ли реально команда `py -m allure serve %allure_result_folder%`
   или все таки надо замарачиваться с такими болезнями?
3. Есть ли какая-то упрощенная схема с allure где нужно наличие только python?
4. А команда allure serve вообще генерирует отчет - именно html файл? А то я не увидел и как-то грустно.

Итого, пример для gitlab+pytest_html:

```yaml
Reports: stage: test script:  
- py -m pytest Tests/Reports.py --html=report_reports.html --self-contained-html --css=reportcss.css  
allow_failure: true
artifacts:  
   when: always  
  paths: - report_reports.html  
   expire_in: 3 days
```

Comment: Вообщем я почитал офф докумекнтацию - https://docs.qameta.io/allure/#_pytest. И прям в ней и написано что надо качать Allure command line и тоже какая-то боль.

Мб кто-то подскажет фреймворк для создания HTML отчетов? 
HTMLTestRunner - валится при запуске в gitlab, причем очень странно - сначала тесты прогоняются, потом пишется надпись - Generate Html Reports - и заново начинают идти тесты, которые сразу валятся. Мб кто сталкивался?

Comment: Вообщем пока самая простая связка для автотестов + gitlab = https://pypi.org/project/pytest-html/.
Ворка в gitlab не падает, и есть файлик, но он выглядит очень стращно, надо как-то придумывать кастомизацию.

Comment: Пример для gitlab-yml  
`Reports:  
  stage: test  
  script:<br/>
    - py -m pytest Tests/Reports.py --html=report_reports.html --self-contained-html --css=reportcss.css<br/>
  allow_failure: true<br/>
  artifacts:<br/>
    when: always<br/>
    paths:<br/>
      - report_reports.html<br/>
    expire_in: 3 days`